# Are there any JavaScript static analysis tools?

Tags: javascript, static-analysis

I'm used to having my compiler complain when I do something stupid like a typo on a variable name but JavaScript has a habit of letting this pass.

Are there any static analysis tools for JavaScript?

Comment: now a days typescript is your friend - it supports javascript implicit type checking and if you want to go 100% you can write jsdoc3 or google closure annotations and it will infer types from there. Editors like vscode or webstorm support it out of the box : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Checking-JavaScript-Files

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I agree that JSLint is the best place to start.  Note that [JavaScript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) is distinct from [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  I’d also suggest checking out [JSure](https://github.com/berke/jsure), which in my limited testing did better than either of them, though with some rough edges in the implementation—the Intel Mac version crashed on startup for me, though the PowerPC version ran fine even on Intel, and the Linux version ran fine as well.  (The developer, Berke Durak, said he'd get back to me when this was fixed, but I haven't heard from him.)

Don’t expect as much from JavaScript static analysis as you get from a good C checker.  As Durak told me, “any non-trivial analysis is very difficult due to Javascript's dynamic nature.”

(Another, even more obscure Mac-only bug, this time with JSLint’s Konfabulator widget:  Dragging a BBEdit document icon onto the widget moves the document to the trash.  The developer, Douglas Crockford, hadn’t tried the widget on a Mac.)

10 August 2009:  Today at the [Static Analysis Symposium](http://sas09.cs.ucdavis.edu/), Simon Holm Jensen presented a paper on [TAJS: Type Analyzer for JavaScript](http://www.brics.dk/TAJS/), written with Anders Møller and Peter Thiemann.  The paper doesn’t mention the above tools, but Jensen told me he’d looked at some of them and wasn’t impressed.  The code for TAJS should be available sometime this summer.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: JSLint is available on GitHub.

Comment: @Dave oh right, that's great:)

Comment: The source code for TAJS is now available.

Answer (score 58):

UPDATED ANSWER, 2017: Yes. Use ESLint. http://eslint.org

---

In addition to [JSLint](http://jslint.org) (already mentioned in [Flash Sheridan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/710837/55478)) and the [Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) (previously mentioned in [awhyte's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220180/55478)) I have have also gotten a lot of benefit from running [JSHint](http://jshint.com/about) and [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer).  As of 2012, all four tools are free open-source and have a large and active developer community behind them. They're each a bit different (and I think, complementary) in the kinds of checks they perform:

**JSLint** was designed to be, and still is Douglas Crockford's personal linting tool.  It ships with a *great* default ruleset -- Crockford's own, [constantly updated](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commits/master/) as he [continues to learn](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/msearch?date=any&DM=------------&DD=----&DY=----&DM2=------------&DD2=----&DY2=----&AM=contains&AT=douglas&SM=contains&ST=&MM=contains&MT=%22try+it+now%22&charset=UTF-8) about JavaScript and its pitfalls. JSLint is [highly opinionated](https://gist.github.com/1745829) and this is generally [seen as a good thing.](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#JSLint) Thus there's (intentionally) a [limited amount](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) you can do to configure or disable individual rules. But this can make it tough to apply JSLint to legacy code.

**JSHint** is very similar to JSLint (in fact it [began life](http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/02/20/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint/) as JSLint fork) but it is easier/possible to [configure or disable](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) all of JSLint's checks via command line options or via a [`.jshintrc` file](https://npmjs.org/package/jshint).

I particularly like that I can tell JSHint to report *all* of the errors in a file, even if there are hundreds of errors. By contrast, although JSLint does have a `maxerr` configuration option, it will generally bail out relatively early when attempting to process files that contain large numbers of errors.

**The Closure compiler** is extremely useful in that, if code *won't* compile with Closure, you can feel very certain said code *is* deeply hosed in some fundamental way.  Closure compilation is possibly the closest thing that there is in the JS world to an "interpreter" syntax check like `php -l` or `ruby -c`

Closure also [warns you about potential issues](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref) such as missing parameters and undeclared or redefined variables.  If you aren't seeing the warnings you expect, try increasing the warning level by invoking Closure with an option of `--warning_level VERBOSE`

**PHP CodeSniffer** [can parse JavaScript](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Tokenizers/JS.php) as well as PHP and CSS.  CodeSniffer ships with several different coding standards, (say `phpcs -i` to see them) which include many useful sniffs for JavaScript code including checks against [inline control structures](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/Generic/Sniffs/ControlStructures/InlineControlStructureSniff.php) and [superfluous whitespace](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/Squiz/Sniffs/WhiteSpace/SuperfluousWhitespaceSniff.php).

Here is a [list of JavaScript sniffs](https://gist.github.com/3375708#file_js_code_sniffs.md) available in PHP CodeSniffer as of version 1.3.6 and here is a [custom ruleset that would allow you to run them all at once.](https://gist.github.com/3375708#file_js_sniffs.xml)  Using custom rulesets, it's easy to [pick and choose the rules](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.annotated-ruleset.php) you want to apply.  And you can even [write your own sniffs](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.coding-standard-tutorial.php) if you want to enforce a particular "house style" that isn't supported out of the box.  Afaik CodeSniffer is the only tool of the four mentioned here that supports customization and creation of new static analysis rules.  One caveat though: CodeSniffer is also the slowest-running of any of the tools mentioned.

Comment: Copy-paste detection for JavaScript code is now available via CPD. To my knowledge this is the first robust open source code duplication tool for JavaScript! http://pmd.sourceforge.net and see also the question "Is there CPD like tool for javascript?" http://stackoverflow.com/a/13745190/55478

Answer (score 20):

[Google's "Closure" JS compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) produces configurable warnings and errors at compile-time.  It definitely finds misspelled variables and methods, plus arity mistakes.  If you're willing to write JsDoc the Closure way, it can do a lot with type information, too.

The YUI "Compressor" tool can produce warnings too, but haven't tried it yet.

I haven't had much luck with the Aptana IDE, built on Eclipse, but other people like it.  See Stack Overflow discussion of JS IDEs.

The IntelliJ IDE, which isn't free last I checked, has frickin' excellent JS support.  It will detect and highlight misspelled vars and methods as you type, and more.  It's got autocomplete, too.

Answer (score 11):

In summary, JSLint, JSHint, Plato, ESLint, Google Closure-Linter are the tools available. 
I faced installation issues while trying out Google Closure-Linter for Windows. But, it does mention on the web page that its support for Windows is experimental.
I found and tried another tool which works well. Here is the link for it: 
http://esprima.org/

Also, this is the github link for the tool Esprima:
https://github.com/ariya/esprima

Answer (score 7):

You can see some tools for JavaScript static code analysis in this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#JavaScript).

A tool in the Wiki, but not mentioned in this post, is [DeepScan](https://deepscan.io).
Its focus is to find runtime errors and quality issues rather than coding conventions of linters. It covers also TypeScript, React and Vue.js.

You can try it out for your GitHub project.

Answer (score 6):

I tried out ESlint and found it good..you can also add custom rules there..Here is the github repo: https://github.com/nzakas/eslint and here is the introduction to it: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/16/introducing-eslint/

Answer (score 4):

More security focused than general purpose list can be found on the Mozilla Wiki at [Security/B2G/JavaScript code analysis](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/B2G/JavaScript_code_analysis)

> The purpose of this document is to collect JavaScript code analysis
> tools suitable for including in coming Mozilla projects or for
> internal use.

Also there is at least one commercial product that does security analysis:  [Burp gets new JavaScript analysis capabilities](http://blog.portswigger.net/2014/07/burp-gets-new-javascript-analysis.html)

> The latest release of Burp includes a new engine for static analysis of JavaScript code. This enables Burp Scanner to report a range of new vulnerabilities, including:
>
> - DOM-based XSS
> - JavaScript injection
> - Client-side SQL injection
> - WebSocket hijacking
> - Local file path manipulation
> - DOM-based open redirection
> - Cookie manipulation
> - Ajax request header manipulation
> - DOM-based denial of service
> - Web message manipulation
> - HTML5 storage manipulation

Answer (score 4):

In the commercial realm, [**Coverity Static Analysis**](http://www.coverity.com/products/code-advisor/) supports analysis of JavaScript as of version 7.7 (mid-2015).  Regarding your specific inquiry about typos, my pet project appearing in the latest release (8.0, beginning of 2016) **does find typos** in names of program elements.

As a key developer on the project, please accept my shameless plug: Though not yet as mature as the [venerated C/C++ analysis](http://www.coverity.com/press-releases/cern-chooses-coverity-to-ensure-accuracy-of-large-hadron-collider-software/), Coverity's JavaScript analysis shares much of the same engine, with the same focus on finding high-value defects with a low rate of false positive defect reports.  We are increasing our focus on finding security defects in JavaScript (and other languages), in addition to finding general programming errors.

Now, here are some typos it finds (exact typo left as an exercise for the reader, to emphasize how easily these can be overlooked):

merge.js: [(stable link)](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/cf7d845552751f6a9a4f1d26ea9f0377e90dfbb3/css-components/www/vendor/codemirror-4.0/addon/merge/merge.js#L356) [(latest revision)](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/css-components/www/vendor/codemirror-4.0/addon/merge/merge.js#L356)

commands-packages-query.js: [(stable link)](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor/blob/e6788b9a223710d66bae9f279b27bf78255ce6b7/tools/commands-packages-query.js#L1119) [(latest revision)](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor/blob/devel/tools/commands-packages-query.js#L1119)

series-pie-tests.js: [(stable link)](https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/25264e3629b1c07fb779d203c4a25c0879ec862c/src/charts/tests/unit/assets/series-pie-tests.js#L382) [(latest revision)](https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/src/charts/tests/unit/assets/series-pie-tests.js#L382)

outline_case.js: [(stable link)](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/blob/5b85498348e01ba59663c03c70da11f13571d20d/frameworks/foundation/tests/controllers/tree/outline_case.js#L99) [(latest revision)](https://github.com/sproutcore/sproutcore/blob/master/frameworks/foundation/tests/controllers/tree/outline_case.js#L99)

Answer (score 3):

I like [Jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) for this sort of thing...

Comment: Cool. I found an Eclipse plugin for JSLint at http://www.rockstarapps.com/joomla-1.5.8/products/jslint-eclipse-plugin.html which looks quite good too. Note that one needs to install from the 'Eclipse Update site for the Beta Version of jsLex 1.2.2' to get the JSLint functionality.

Answer (score 3):

[Flow](http://flowtype.org/) does static analysis with and without annotations.

If you need annotations, the syntax is compatible to [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Install the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-bin) with :

```
npm install --global flow-bin
```

There's also some tooling. Have a look at [gulp-flowtype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-flowtype) and perhaps [SublimeLinter-flow](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-flow)

Answer (score 2):

JSAnalyse has just been published on codeplex. 
It is a tool which analyses the dependencies between javascript files. You can even define the allowed dependencies and JSAnalysis checks whether the defined rules are fulfilled or not. That allows to keep track about the javascript dependencies even in big projects and have a clean architecture.

JSAnalyse can be executed as a command line tool or configured via the Visual Studio Layer Diagramm. It is also easy to integrate into the build. With gated check-ins you can keep the dependencies under control.

http://jsanalyse.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Our [SD ECMAScript CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/ECMAScriptCloneDR.html) is a tool for finding exact and near-miss copies of duplicated code across large JavaScript source code bases.

It uses the language syntax to guide the detection, so it will find clones in spite of format changes, inserted/deleted comments, renamed variables and even some inserted/deleted statements.

The site has a sample CloneDR run on Google's Closure library.

Comment: has anyone tried this one yet? Didn't find any download or order buttons...

Comment: ... Since January 2011... there's a download link that you can use to get an eval copy of CloneDR for JavaScript (or a number of other languages) to play with.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, I'm behind this: http://www.toptensoftware.com/minime which does minification, obfuscation and a reasonable set of lint style checks.