# JS validator alternatives to JSLint?

Tags: javascript, validation

Is JSLint *it* as far as js validation tools go, or are there others?

Comment: As far as I know, JSLint is it. If not the only, then likely the best.

Comment: Might be worth checking out - "Are there any Javascript static analysis tools?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534601/are-there-any-javascript-static-analysis-tools

Comment: JSLint is definitely angling towards a specific code style - it's less of a problem finder and more of a "Douglas Crockford wouldn't like it" tool.

Answer (score 31):

There are two good ones that I know of:

- [ESLint](http://eslint.org/)
- [JSHint](http://jshint.com/)

Comment: I ran some of our code through JSHint, and it looks great.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Closure Linter is deprecated and not maintained any more.

Answer (score 5):

A recent addition to the list: https://github.com/eslint/eslint

All the rules are implemented as plugins so it's easy to add your own

Answer (score 3):

JSHint, JavaScript Lint (cites JSLint as main source for inspiration, and has similarities and even borrowed code, but is different), Esprima (calls JavaScript by a different name, but is the same thing, "ECMAscript"), and any that other answers listed that I didn't include in this list.

Also, I believe there are plug-ins for eclipse and other IDEs that can be used that are implementations of the mentioned validators, as well as Apache Ant tasks.

Some Useful links:

http://www.jshint.com/

http://www.javascriptlint.com/index.htm

http://esprima.org/index.html

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/01/26/javascript-validation-with-jshint-eclipse/
(article on plug-in)

http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/
(Installation link)

https://github.com/ariya/ant-javascript-validate (apache ant task)

Also, here is a more comprehensive tool going beyond just JavaScript validation, but doing additional things as well:  https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia only lists jslint but there is another at [javascriptlint.com](http://javascriptlint.com/) you could try.

Answer (score 2):

[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), the [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) JavaScript compiler and [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) are all robust, community-supported JavaScript validation tools. Each ships with its own set of rules, which you can modify to some extent (CodeSniffer is the most flexible in terms of customization).  For JSLint users, JSHint may be the most interesting option as it was [originally intended](http://anton.kovalyov.net/2011/02/20/why-i-forked-jslint-to-jshint/) to be a less strict fork of JSLint.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12005175/55478) to the question ["Are There Any JavaScript Static Analysis Tools?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534601/are-there-any-javascript-static-analysis-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, I'm behind this: http://www.toptensoftware.com/minime which does minification, obfuscation and a reasonable set of lint style checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Closure Linter](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/) which is also available as a [Grunt package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-closure-linter)