# What tools other than jslint exist to validate and check Javascript syntax and style?

Tags: javascript, syntax

In our current project we are using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) for verifying that Javacript is written correctly, and that it satisfies a few style checks. This is included as an Ant task in our `build.xml`.

However, I have found that the [license of JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js) makes it [incompatible with free and open-source software](http://wonko.com/post/jsmin-isnt-welcome-on-google-code):

> // The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil.

I also find JSLint a bit *too* overzealous in its checks, and [makes JQuery-based development difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354838/39531). I understand that its intent is not to help one develop scripts, but to check that the script will work in most existing language implementations.

Finally, it's just not smart enough with its scoping: what's wrong with defining a variable in the head of a `for` loop? (i.e. `for (var i = 0; ...)` rather than `var i; for (i = 0; ...)`).

(**EDIT:** This is actually a problem with Javascript itself. *JavaScript does not have block scope*, unlike most C-like languages.)

What alternatives exist for verifying the syntax and style for Javascript scripts, intended to be executed within modern web browsers? Any implementation language is fine. I've even thought about using the [Rhino library](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) to load and execute the script within Java.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208604/js-validator-alternatives-to-jslint for some options

Comment: Still waiting for a valid answer - so far, only a JSLint fork and a different language have been suggested. (For what it's worth, Rhino JS is also useful for linting syntax but not style.)

Answer (score 1):

Use **JSHint**: http://www.jshint.com/

Comment: JSHint is based on JSLint and thus has the exact same incompatible software license.

Comment: @jevon: According to https://github.com/versatica/JsSIP/issues/77, it looks like Crockford gave a pristine MIT license to the Eclipse Foundation, who then shared it with JSHint.

Answer (score 0):

JSHint does not have the same license as JSLint. In a sense it does have an MIT license without the  'Do no evil' addition of JSLint. See the github link:
[jsHint license on gitHub](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/LICENSE)

Comment: JSHint itself might be under standard MIT, but unless JSHint has totally removed any dependency or reuse of JSLint, or Crockford has granted JSLint an exemption, AFAIK it's still bound by the "do no evil" clause of JSLint. It's still labelled a "fork of JSLint".

Answer (score 0):

Why not try TypeScript? its much better than any "checker" JS can provide and generates great code. Its also type-safe and a leaner-meaner language. Just an opinion.

Comment: Of course one can use any compile-to-Javascript techniques (e.g. Coffeescript, etc) to improve productivity, but this question is specifically for Javascript linting/testing. (One problem is that they always lack integration with existing tool or debugging frameworks; another is that you assume you are writing code from scratch, rather than modifying existing application Javascript.)