# Tool to draw a Javascript function map?

Tags: javascript

i'm looking for a tool drawing a kind of function usage map (maybe there's a better name for that).

I'm working on a project with many javascript files included in pages. This project has been developped for a while and we've reached a point where this is really messy. I'd like to have a clear view of what is included where, how functions are used, etc. .

Do you know if such a tool exist ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) produces a Function Report which may sort of be what you need, but in general there aren't any good static analysis tools for JavaScript.  (My current project contains a huge amount of duplicated JavaScript developed over 10+ years... we desperately need one too.)

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534601/).