# How to remove dead code from Javascript

Tags: javascript, dead-code

I am trying to remove unused functions from my project. Since it has thousands of lines, this takes forever.

Code coverage tools may suggest functions that are not used in a given test case, but it may be dangerous to rely only on this.

Is there another tool which can help with this?

Comment: I fear that tools are your best option - just use more than one tool and rely on their combined output. Save backup of everything and perform full test of everything before going live.

Answer (score 13):

You can try Google Closure compiler. It has different settings and you can also remove dead code automatically. You can try it here: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

For more info read here: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels.html

Comment: The "advanced" optimization setting removes dead code automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534601/are-there-any-javascript-static-analysis-tools) question regarding Javascript static analysis tools.